# How to find the index of a substring ignoring dots or commas

Tags: javascript, regex

In Angular, I need to find a substring, like 'no this is', without dots or commas, in strings like this:

'No. This is...'

'Hello... no, this is...'

'... no this is...'

The substring to look for could be any text, always without dots or commas, but the expected result should be the original text, like 'No. This is' or 'no, this is'.

I tried replacing using regex:

```
const regex = /[.,]/g;
const textToFind = 'no this is';
let matches = arrayOfTexts.filter(c => c.toLowerCase().replace(regex, '').includes(textToFind.toLowerCase()));
```

This code is finding the matching lines, but I need to get the original text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a more specific regex expression work?
You could do a [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) or [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on something like this:

```
/(no)[., ]*(this)[., ]*(is)/
```

Note: you would probably want to use the [ignoreCase flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/ignoreCase).

Sandbox: https://regex101.com/r/NNCXlu/2

Comment: It worked like a charm. I built the regex from every text to look for. Thanks for the 'i' flag, it was useful too.